# charts is not working in jdeveloper 1.2.2.4.0

Tags: oracle-adf

Good day ,
I'm using oracle j-developer Version 12.2.1.4.0 i'm facing this error while i create Charts :

**Previously reported error [oracle.adfdtinternal.view.common.binding.operation.CreateOperation$CreateOperationXmlCommitException in o.adfdtinternal.view.common.binding.operation.CreateOperation:769]**

This is error :

```
Performing action (297) Clear [ from RunLogPage ] [ for ( <none>, ViewController.jpr, Inventory_App.jws ) ]
Reported by logger: oracle.adfdtinternal.view.common.binding.gallery.ComponentGalleryAction
oracle.adfdtinternal.view.common.binding.operation.CreateOperation$CreateOperationXmlCommitException
oracle.adfdtinternal.view.common.binding.operation.CreateOperation$CreateOperationXmlCommitException
 o.adfdtinternal.view.common.binding.operation.CreateOperation._rollbackAllTransactions(CreateOperation.java:769)
 o.adfdtinternal.view.common.binding.operation.CreateOperation.apply(CreateOperation.java:150)
 o.adfdtinternal.view.common.binding.gallery.ComponentGalleryAction.actionPerformed(ComponentGalleryAction.java:155)
 o.bali.xml.share.ActionProxy.actionPerformed(ActionProxy.java:47)
 o.bali.xml.gui.swing.dnd.DropMenuInvoker$CleanupProxy.access$201(DropMenuInvoker.java:251)
 o.bali.xml.gui.swing.dnd.DropMenuInvoker$CleanupProxy$1.run(DropMenuInvoker.java:271)
 j.a.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:311)
 j.a.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:758)
 j.a.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
 j.a.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
 j.a.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703)
 j.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
 j.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:74)
 j.a.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:728)
 o.javatools.internal.ui.EventQueueWrapper._dispatchEvent(EventQueueWrapper.java:169)
 o.javatools.internal.ui.EventQueueWrapper.dispatchEvent(EventQueueWrapper.java:151)
 j.a.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:205)
 j.a.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
 j.a.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
 j.a.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
 j.a.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
 j.a.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
Caused by:
java.lang.NullPointerException
 j.io.StringReader.<init>(StringReader.java:50)
 o.adfinternal.view.faces.bi.renderkit.common.BaseImageConverterUtils.exportSVGToPNG(BaseImageConverterUtils.java:179)
 o.adfdtinternal.dvt.datapresdt.binding.utils.ChartDataUtils.getBufferedImageFromSVG(ChartDataUtils.java:1090)
 o.adfdtinternal.model.dvt.ide.objects.bindPanels.rowset.CommonBarChartPanel.getDefaultImage(CommonBarChartPanel.java:537)
 o.adfdtinternal.model.dvt.ide.objects.bindPanels.rowset.JSBarChartPanel.createInteractiveImage(JSBarChartPanel.java:118)
 o.adfdtinternal.model.dvt.ide.objects.bindPanels.rowset.CommonChartPanel.addInteractiveImage(CommonChartPanel.java:616)
 o.adfdtinternal.model.dvt.ide.objects.bindPanels.rowset.CommonBarChartPanel.addPanelContent(CommonBarChartPanel.java:1141)
 o.adfdtinternal.model.dvt.ide.objects.bindPanels.rowset.JSBarChartPanel.addPanelContent(JSBarChartPanel.java:164)
 o.adfdtinternal.model.dvt.ide.objects.bindPanels.rowset.BaseGraph.initialize(BaseGraph.java:125)
 o.adfdtinternal.model.dvt.ide.objects.bindPanels.rowset.JSChartBindingPanel.createBindingPanel(JSChartBindingPanel.java:109)
 o.adfdtinternal.model.dvt.ide.objects.bindPanels.rowset.GraphBindingPanel.addPanelContent(GraphBindingPanel.java:196)
 o.adfdtinternal.model.dvt.ide.objects.bindPanels.rowset.BaseGraph.initialize(BaseGraph.java:125)
 o.adfdtinternal.model.dvt.ide.objects.editors.CommonChartEditor.createEditPanel(CommonChartEditor.java:190)
 o.adfdtinternal.model.ide.objects.editors.JUDTObjectEditor.findOrCreateEditPanel(JUDTObjectEditor.java:177)
 o.adfdtinternal.model.ide.objects.editors.JUDTObjectEditor.prepareEditor(JUDTObjectEditor.java:255)
 o.adfdtinternal.model.ide.objects.editors.JUDTObjectEditor.showEditorInDialog(JUDTObjectEditor.java:222)
 o.adfdtinternal.model.dvt.ide.objects.editors.DvtCommonEditor.showEditorInDialog(DvtCommonEditor.java:78)
 o.adfdtinternal.dvt.datapresdt.binding.binder.DvtCommonBinder.launchBindingEditor(DvtCommonBinder.java:106)
 o.adfdtinternal.dvt.datapresdt.binding.binder.DvtCommonBinder$1.run(DvtCommonBinder.java:61)
 o.adfdt.jdev.transaction.JDevTransactionManager$1.performTask(JDevTransactionManager.java:63)
 o.bali.xml.model.task.StandardTransactionTask.runWithTokenThrowingXCE(StandardTransactionTask.java:236)
 o.bali.xml.model.task.StandardTransactionTask.runThrowingXCE(StandardTransactionTask.java:151)
 o.adfdt.jdev.transaction.JDevTransactionManager.runTaskUnderTransaction(JDevTransactionManager.java:86)
 o.adfdtinternal.dvt.datapresdt.binding.binder.DvtCommonBinder.displayBindingUI(DvtCommonBinder.java:77)
 o.adfdtinternal.dvt.datapresdt.binding.binder.DvtBaseBinder.populateBinding(DvtBaseBinder.java:78)
 o.adfdtinternal.dvt.datapresdt.binding.binder.DvtBaseBinder.bind(DvtBaseBinder.java:43)
 o.adfdtinternal.view.common.binding.creator.XmlBasedCreatorInfo._bind(XmlBasedCreatorInfo.java:1075)
 o.adfdtinternal.view.common.binding.creator.XmlBasedCreatorInfo.create(XmlBasedCreatorInfo.java:461)
 o.adfdtinternal.view.common.binding.datatransfer.ADFDocumentFragmentCreatorInfo.createDocumentFragment(ADFDocumentFragmentCreatorInfo.java:83)
 o.adfdtinternal.view.common.binding.operation.CreateOperation.apply(CreateOperation.java:112)
 o.adfdtinternal.view.common.binding.gallery.ComponentGalleryAction.actionPerformed(ComponentGalleryAction.java:155)
 o.bali.xml.share.ActionProxy.actionPerformed(ActionProxy.java:47)
 o.bali.xml.gui.swing.dnd.DropMenuInvoker$CleanupProxy.access$201(DropMenuInvoker.java:251)
 o.bali.xml.gui.swing.dnd.DropMenuInvoker$CleanupProxy$1.run(DropMenuInvoker.java:271)
 j.a.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:311)
 j.a.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:758)
 j.a.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
 j.a.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
 j.a.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703)
 j.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
 j.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:74)
 j.a.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:728)
 o.javatools.internal.ui.EventQueueWrapper._dispatchEvent(EventQueueWrapper.java:169)
 o.javatools.internal.ui.EventQueueWrapper.dispatchEvent(EventQueueWrapper.java:151)
 j.a.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:205)
 j.a.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
 j.a.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
 j.a.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
 j.a.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
 j.a.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
Reported by logger: oracle.adfdtinternal.view.common.binding.gallery.ComponentGalleryAction
oracle.adfdtinternal.view.common.binding.operation.CreateOperation$CreateOperationXmlCommitException
oracle.adfdtinternal.view.common.binding.operation.CreateOperation$CreateOperationXmlCommitException
 o.adfdtinternal.view.common.binding.operation.CreateOperation._rollbackAllTransactions(CreateOperation.java:769)
 o.adfdtinternal.view.common.binding.operation.CreateOperation.apply(CreateOperation.java:150)
 o.adfdtinternal.view.common.binding.gallery.ComponentGalleryAction.actionPerformed(ComponentGalleryAction.java:155)
 o.bali.xml.share.ActionProxy.actionPerformed(ActionProxy.java:47)
 o.bali.xml.gui.swing.dnd.DropMenuInvoker$CleanupProxy.access$201(DropMenuInvoker.java:251)
 o.bali.xml.gui.swing.dnd.DropMenuInvoker$CleanupProxy$1.run(DropMenuInvoker.java:271)
 j.a.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:311)
 j.a.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:758)
 j.a.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
 j.a.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
 j.a.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703)
 j.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
 j.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:74)
 j.a.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:728)
 o.javatools.internal.ui.EventQueueWrapper._dispatchEvent(EventQueueWrapper.java:169)
 o.javatools.internal.ui.EventQueueWrapper.dispatchEvent(EventQueueWrapper.java:151)
 j.a.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:205)
 j.a.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
 j.a.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
 j.a.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
 j.a.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
 j.a.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
Caused by:
java.lang.NullPointerException
 j.io.StringReader.<init>(StringReader.java:50)
 o.adfinternal.view.faces.bi.renderkit.common.BaseImageConverterUtils.exportSVGToPNG(BaseImageConverterUtils.java:179)
 o.adfdtinternal.dvt.datapresdt.binding.utils.ChartDataUtils.getBufferedImageFromSVG(ChartDataUtils.java:1090)
 o.adfdtinternal.model.dvt.ide.objects.bindPanels.rowset.CommonBarChartPanel.getDefaultImage(CommonBarChartPanel.java:537)
 o.adfdtinternal.model.dvt.ide.objects.bindPanels.rowset.JSBarChartPanel.createInteractiveImage(JSBarChartPanel.java:118)
 o.adfdtinternal.model.dvt.ide.objects.bindPanels.rowset.CommonChartPanel.addInteractiveImage(CommonChartPanel.java:616)
 o.adfdtinternal.model.dvt.ide.objects.bindPanels.rowset.CommonBarChartPanel.addPanelContent(CommonBarChartPanel.java:1141)
 o.adfdtinternal.model.dvt.ide.objects.bindPanels.rowset.JSBarChartPanel.addPanelContent(JSBarChartPanel.java:164)
 o.adfdtinternal.model.dvt.ide.objects.bindPanels.rowset.BaseGraph.initialize(BaseGraph.java:125)
 o.adfdtinternal.model.dvt.ide.objects.bindPanels.rowset.JSChartBindingPanel.createBindingPanel(JSChartBindingPanel.java:109)
 o.adfdtinternal.model.dvt.ide.objects.bindPanels.rowset.GraphBindingPanel.addPanelContent(GraphBindingPanel.java:196)
 o.adfdtinternal.model.dvt.ide.objects.bindPanels.rowset.BaseGraph.initialize(BaseGraph.java:125)
 o.adfdtinternal.model.dvt.ide.objects.editors.CommonChartEditor.createEditPanel(CommonChartEditor.java:190)
 o.adfdtinternal.model.ide.objects.editors.JUDTObjectEditor.findOrCreateEditPanel(JUDTObjectEditor.java:177)
 o.adfdtinternal.model.ide.objects.editors.JUDTObjectEditor.prepareEditor(JUDTObjectEditor.java:255)
 o.adfdtinternal.model.ide.objects.editors.JUDTObjectEditor.showEditorInDialog(JUDTObjectEditor.java:222)
 o.adfdtinternal.model.dvt.ide.objects.editors.DvtCommonEditor.showEditorInDialog(DvtCommonEditor.java:78)
 o.adfdtinternal.dvt.datapresdt.binding.binder.DvtCommonBinder.launchBindingEditor(DvtCommonBinder.java:106)
 o.adfdtinternal.dvt.datapresdt.binding.binder.DvtCommonBinder$1.run(DvtCommonBinder.java:61)
 o.adfdt.jdev.transaction.JDevTransactionManager$1.performTask(JDevTransactionManager.java:63)
 o.bali.xml.model.task.StandardTransactionTask.runWithTokenThrowingXCE(StandardTransactionTask.java:236)
 o.bali.xml.model.task.StandardTransactionTask.runThrowingXCE(StandardTransactionTask.java:151)
 o.adfdt.jdev.transaction.JDevTransactionManager.runTaskUnderTransaction(JDevTransactionManager.java:86)
 o.adfdtinternal.dvt.datapresdt.binding.binder.DvtCommonBinder.displayBindingUI(DvtCommonBinder.java:77)
 o.adfdtinternal.dvt.datapresdt.binding.binder.DvtBaseBinder.populateBinding(DvtBaseBinder.java:78)
 o.adfdtinternal.dvt.datapresdt.binding.binder.DvtBaseBinder.bind(DvtBaseBinder.java:43)
 o.adfdtinternal.view.common.binding.creator.XmlBasedCreatorInfo._bind(XmlBasedCreatorInfo.java:1075)
 o.adfdtinternal.view.common.binding.creator.XmlBasedCreatorInfo.create(XmlBasedCreatorInfo.java:461)
 o.adfdtinternal.view.common.binding.datatransfer.ADFDocumentFragmentCreatorInfo.createDocumentFragment(ADFDocumentFragmentCreatorInfo.java:83)
 o.adfdtinternal.view.common.binding.operation.CreateOperation.apply(CreateOperation.java:112)
 o.adfdtinternal.view.common.binding.gallery.ComponentGalleryAction.actionPerformed(ComponentGalleryAction.java:155)
 o.bali.xml.share.ActionProxy.actionPerformed(ActionProxy.java:47)
 o.bali.xml.gui.swing.dnd.DropMenuInvoker$CleanupProxy.access$201(DropMenuInvoker.java:251)
 o.bali.xml.gui.swing.dnd.DropMenuInvoker$CleanupProxy$1.run(DropMenuInvoker.java:271)
 j.a.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:311)
 j.a.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:758)
 j.a.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
 j.a.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
 j.a.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703)
 j.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
 j.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:74)
 j.a.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:728)
 o.javatools.internal.ui.EventQueueWrapper._dispatchEvent(EventQueueWrapper.java:169)
 o.javatools.internal.ui.EventQueueWrapper.dispatchEvent(EventQueueWrapper.java:151)
 j.a.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:205)
 j.a.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
 j.a.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
 j.a.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
 j.a.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
 j.a.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
```